# Как рассчитать переносы в тексте?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, текст

Мне надо на изображение вывести многострочный текст. Вывожу через `QPainter.drawText`. Он как я понял умеет выводить многострочный текст если ему указать рект, но ставить переносы в тексте с помощью `'\n'` надо самому. Исходя из того что у меня уже заранее будут координаты рамки в которую надо выводить как мне рассчитать где ставить переносы?

Если точнее мне надо знать хотя-бы сколько символов поместится на одной строке в этой рамке с учетом текущего шрифта? Как соотносится размер шрифта и пиксели? Я измерял - размер шрифта явно не в пикселях задается, т.к. на полученном изображении один символ занимает намного меньше места чем был задан размер шрифта.

Comment: Есть такая штука как QFontMetrics. Да и судя по документации drawText умеет делать перенос слов: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawText-13 и http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawText-14

Comment: @gil9red вы абсолютно правы, спасибо! Я не нашел сразу там есть флаг Qt.TextWordWrap с которым все отлично переносится. 

У меня только один вопрос остался. Не по теме, но короткий... Qt откуда тянет шрифты? Класс QFont принимает просто имя шрифта. Это удобно, но я опасаюсь что на винде это у меня норм работает, а на сервере где старый CentOS будут какие-нибудь проблемы... Он системные шрифты тянет или они с библиотекой прямо идут? И еще я не нашел способа как загрузить шрифт из файла (явно указав путь)? Мало-ли... Вдруг понадобится.

Comment: Скорее всего системные. Но, qt может подгружать пользовательские шрифты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/57b10cfc4dcead59cbde3db15ef8630b385b9bcd/pyqt5__draw_text_with_word_wrap.py) показывает что с флагом `Qt.TextWordWrap` для одного и того же размера области, слова переносятся:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect


app = QApplication([])

text = "Hello World!"

pixmap = QPixmap(180, 130)
pixmap.fill(Qt.white)

painter = QPainter(pixmap)
painter.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))

rect = QRect(0, 0, 70, 50)
painter.drawRect(rect)
painter.drawText(rect, Qt.TextWordWrap, text)

rect = QRect(0, 60, 70, 50)
painter.drawRect(rect)
painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignLeft, text)

w = QLabel()
w.setPixmap(pixmap)
w.show()

app.exec()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]